# After validating successfully, how to modify input for smarter displaying

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webcontrol

My case is that I have a textbox for Age input. I use RegularExpressionValidator control to validate the input, like this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ... ValidationExpression="\s*\d+\s*" ... />
```

The validation accepts digit inputs which maybe include whitespaces on the beginning or at the end of numbers.
So if one user types "   32    " into the textbox, the input is legal. But afterwards I want the text box shows the better form, "32" - throw away all whitespaces.

I know it is possible to process by javascript, however is there a shorter way? or another more powerful validator control?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why you would allow them to enter spaces.  Why not just use a RangeValadator or a CompareValidator (to type int)?

Comment: @TrueDevelopment: Thanks for your suggest. I just dont want users have to input again if they only type one redundant space while the validator is stil able to filter numbers.

Comment: The only client side solution I could think of is using JS.  Otherwise, if a PostBack is involved, just `Trim()` the value.